# Deserialize parent/child classes with different config with Jackson

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I'm working on a Restful application with Spring Boot and I've defined my classes as below:

```
class Organization {
    String name;
}

class Base {
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    Organization org;
}

class Car extends Base{
  //other members
}

class FlattenCar extends Car {
    @JsonUnwrapped(prefix = "org_")
    Organization org;
}
```

Now what happened is, deserializing the org object depends on the first time call. It means, if I deserialize Car at the first time, next calls on deserializing FlattenCar doesn't unwrap org and vice versa.
I know that I hid org member, but it seems the first time deserializing is cached!
Who knows where is the problem and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that have in your Base class the option READ_ONLY (only for serialization), when it should be WRITE_ONLY if only want to take this property into account in the deserialization.

> READ_ONLY: Access setting that means that the property may only be read
> for serialization, but not written (set) during deserialization.
>
> WRITE_ONLY: Access setting that means that the property may only be
> written (set) for deserialization, but will not be read (get) on
> serialization, that is, the value of the property is not included in
> serialization.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@RestController
public class API {
    
    @Data
    public static class Organization {
        private String name;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Base {
        @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
        private Organization org;
    }
    
    @Getter @Setter
    public static class Car extends Base {
        private String prop1;
    };
    
    @Getter @Setter
    public static class FlattenCar extends Car { 
        private String prop2;
    };
    
    @PostMapping("/car")
    public Car deserializeCar(@RequestBody Car car) {
        System.out.println("Car: " + car);
        return car;
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/flatten_car")
    public FlattenCar deserializeFlattenCar(@RequestBody FlattenCar flattenCar) {
        System.out.println("Flatten: " + flattenCar);
        return flattenCar;
    }
    
}
```

Ouput:

```
Flatten: API.Base(org=API.Organization(name=Org. Test))
Car: API.Base(org=API.Organization(name=Org. Test))
```

Remember that Car/CarFlatten class's to_string method has been inherit of Base class in this example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but with this solution we just hide Organization from output JSON. I want to change behavior of serializing in subclasses of a hierarchy.